# How to administer Hadoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop

i have running 4 nodes hadoop cluster and i am asking about any way to administer that cluster remotely

for example

administering the cluster from my laptop for

- executing MapReduce tasks
- disabling or enabling data nodes

is there any way to do that remotely ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Cloudera distribution, the Cloudera Manager webapp would let you do that.
Other distributions may have similar control apps. That would give you per-node control.

For executing MR tasks, you would setup normally submit the job from an external node anyway, pointing to the correct JobTracker and NameNode. So I'm not sure what else you're asking for there.

Comment: Thank you rgordan, that is what i am asking for but for apache hadoop not cloudera distribution of hadoop , are you have any idea for per-node control in apache hadoop

Comment: You could try the dfsadmin command: Add configuration parameter: dfs.hosts.exclude, and let it point it to a file which include the nodes you want to remove. Then invoke command:

'bin/hadoop dfsadmin -refreshNodes'

followed by 

'bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report' to see the results in action.